# Git - Can't see the diff marks anymore

Tags: git, merge, conflict, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I got a conflict on a file and I tried to resolve it using one of my favorit editor (vim or sublime text) but when I opened the file I can't see the diff marks in the file anymore (`<<<<<<< HEAD`, `=======`, `>>>>>>>`).

I'm still able to use vim as `git merge-tool` and get the editor splitted in 4 windows MERGED / BASE / LOCAL / REMOTE , but I'd rather prefer to come back to the one file editing solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are different types of conflicts. You would see these marks in "text conflicts" only. Are you sure yours are really text conflicts and not something else?

Comment: You have a point here I'll check my ```.gitattributes``` to see if they are not treated as binary or something.